# Wrap text from clipboard with tags

Tags: macos, automation, text-input

Every day I have to add {quote} tags at the start and end of text from clipboard. It happens because I add stacktraces to our Jira and these stacktraces should be introduced with {quote} tags.  Is there any way to do it automatically? For example via automator or something else?